# Need a Query to get worksheet manager hierarchy for a parameter in BI-publisher?

Tags: mysql, sql, bi-publisher

```
select distinct cch.emp_person_id 
from cmp_cwb_hrchy cch, cmp_cwb_person_info ccpi
where ccpi.WS_MGR_PERSON_EVENT_ID=cch.MGR_PERSON_EVENT_ID
and ccpi.PERSON_EVENT_ID=cch.EMP_PERSON_EVENT_ID
and ccpi.assignment_id=cch.emp_assignment_id
and ccpi.WS_MGR_ASSIGNMENT_ID=cch.MGR_ASSIGNMENT_ID
```

/* now i want to add decode or case statment. The condition will be if :mgr_id parameter passes manager_id and lvl_num=1(for direct reports) then cch.emp_person_id should be displayed, else all the employees should be passed, means lvl_num=1 will not be considered.*/

Comment: and one more thing parameter drop down will be direct reports and all workers.

Comment: What are you using "distinct" for? What language is this for; the SQL select side, or the BI Publisher side?

Comment: it is sql query